# GoDaddy API - Domain unit price value

Tags: c#, postman, godaddy-api

Using API, I am trying to fetch domain availability and its price in GoDaddy. However, the price shown  on the front end GoDaddy webpage($11.99) doesn't match on the price fetch through API($7490000).

[image]
[Sample data tried from the POSTMAN API call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MetDy.png)

Answer (score 5):

The problem can be due to OTE server not having updated database but one should not neglect the following facts below.

As per the [link](https://pk.godaddy.com/community/VPS-Dedicated-Servers/Incorrect-price-shown-in-Godaddy-api-response/td-p/35473).

> Sorry about this is confusion. The price given is in a format called
> currency-micro-unit. This is to help with oddities around different
> currencies and decimals. If you divide the price by 10^6 you'll get
> the correct value and decimal placement

So in your case it is 7.49$ (7490000÷10^6). Also the price is as follows:

> Price of the domain excluding taxes or fees. Only returned if tld is
> offered

as per the [response model for DomainAvailableResponse in developer doc](https://developer.godaddy.com/doc/endpoint/domains#/v1)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you were using the OTE (test environment) and not production.